# Browser automatically validates a non-mandatory field with an empty value

Tags: html, validation

I have a simple form which contains an `<input>` intended for filling in email addresses should the user decide to do so, i.e. the field is not mandatory. I also use the `type="email"` attribute as it helps with autocompletion as well as it particularly benefits smartphone users - it causes their keyboards to rearrange in order to facilitate email input.

However, there are also users with not as advanced mobile devices who may have some difficulties with typing the `@` sign. Also, there still exist some desktop users who cannot type it either; I know some personally and I presume that there are many more. For these users I set the initial value of the `<input>` to `@`. I shall stress that this is not a placeholder.

But now these two things clash. The browsers' native form validation mechanisms activated by the `type="email"` now prevent form submission since they do not understand that the field is not mandatory and that I do not mind users sending the `@` as the value.

Is there some way to tell the browser to validate the field **only if** the value is not `@` or empty string? Obviously, it would be really easy to make my own validator using javascript but I would not like to resort to that.

Or is my premise about users unable to type the `@` sign false and I could solve this issue by simply leaving the `<input>` empty in the first place? Is there any research on this matter? I still occasionally see relatively recent complaints by desperate users on various tech forums and I imagine that the vast majority of similar inexperienced users does not go ask online, perhaps because they do not even know how to.

Or should I use the good old `type="text"`?

How do you think I should approach this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't know about your user group, but in general I'd think that people are aware of email-addresses and at least know how to write those. Also if you look at websites like Facebook with 1,11 billion users and no "@" sign in the email-text-box, it seems people can handle it. - Again, check your user-group, might be very different from facebook, and answer the question for yourself. Also if somebody doesn't know how to write an "@", this person most probably won't have an email-address in first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the only way to disable User agent validation is to add a `novalidate` to your form. Obviously this would disable all UA validation on the form and not just the one input. Maybe you could use Javascript validation for all your other inputs and use `input[type="text"]` for everything else.

```
<form novalidate>
    <input type="email" value="@">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I would use javascript to alter the field depending on the user agent.

Its a real shame that the W3C didn't think of this, surely a simple `novalidate` on the input would suffice, I really hope this gets fixed, otherwise all `input[type="*"]` are kind of useless for future use.